# call JavaScript function in $(document).ready(function() {})

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to run a ajax function in page load and `onChange`, below is my code:

```
function ajax_get_subject(ID)
{
    alert('function called');
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax_get_subject.php', 
        data: {CourseID: ID},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data)
        {
            if(data['error'] == null)
            {
                //do something
            }
            else
            {
                //do something
            }
        },
        error: function(ts)
        {
            alert("AJAX Error: \n" + ts.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

Below is `ready()` function where I call the `ajax_get_subject` function:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //populate at 1st when page load
    $(function()
    {
        var ID = <?php echo $CourseID?>;
        ajax_get_subject(ID);
    });
});
```

The function `ajax_get_subject` is not triggered. But if I call the function in $('element').change(), it works. Is there any wrong with my code?

Comment: What is the value of `$courseID`? I assume you have a syntax errors (look at the console). Also, having two nested `document.ready` calls is unnecessary. Either remove `$(document).ready(...)` or `$(function() {...})`. `alert` **is not** a debugging tool. Use the browser's developer tools, `console.log` and breakpoints.

Comment: I think you're trying to use PHP code inside JS files that are not executed by PHP. You have to move declaration somewhere to HTML file.

Comment: Change the line `var ID = <?php echo $CourseID?>;` to `var ID = <?php echo $CourseID;  ?>;` and see if it works.

Comment: Why are you embedding `$(function(){})` inside of `$(document).ready()`.  Makes no sense.  Both are doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a syntax error, which at line `var ID = <?php echo $CourseID?>;`, thank you @Felix Kling for mention it in the comment. 
The value of `$CourseID` is a string but without double quotes, I just simply change the code to `var ID = "<?php echo $CourseID?>";` and it works. 
And also thanks for mention on problem of nested `document.ready()`

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to use PHP code inside JS files that are not executed by PHP. You have to move declaration somewhere to HTML file.

#### Suggested solution

I often define PHP values at the top of the file in order to use them in JavaScript, for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.phpValues = window.phpValues || {};
            window.phpValues.courseId = '<?php echo $CourseId ?>';
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/your/script.js">
    </head>
    ....
</html>
```

...then in your `script.js` you can use it as:

```
$(window).ready(function() {
    alert(phpValues.courseId); // alerts value of $CourseID
});
```